# Is it "naming" or "indexing" that determines how Firestore realtime listeners in "collection groups" are scaled?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

in the Firestore documentation [understanding realtime listerners at scale](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/real-time_queries_at_scale) it says:

> **Use efficient listeners**
> As the write rates for your database increase, Cloud Firestore splits the data processing across many servers. Cloud Firestore's sharding algorithm tries to co-locate data from the same collection or collection group onto the same changelog server. The system tries to maximize the possible write throughput while keeping the number of servers involved in the processing of a query as low as possible.

If I have many subcollections with the same name, but they aren't indexed with a collectionGroup query, will they be co-located onto the same changelog server or not?

I expect them not to be co-located, but I can't really find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documents in those subcollections themselves will indeed not be colocated. Only a collection group index on that group would colocate data, and thus increase chances of a hotspot on it.